# GetOptions and Command Line (Perl)

Tags: perl, command-line

I'm currently having an issue using GetOptions.

Let's say I have this chunk of code:

```
my $var1;
my $var2;

GetOptions (
    'option1=s' => \$var1,
    'option2=s' => \$var2,
);
```

When I'm running my script on the command line, I'm trying to avoid this particular case.

> myprog.pl --option1 --option2 arg1 arg2 (so on and so forth)

where option1 would be assigned --option2 in $var1, which is obviously not my intentions as I want:

> myprog.pl --option1 something --option2 somethingElse ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So you want the value of `--option1` to be optional?  Use `:s` instead of `=s`.

```
my $var1;
my $var2;

GetOptions (
    'option1:s' => \$var1,
    'option2=s' => \$var2,
);
```

Comment: I think what he wants is for `--option1` to look past the `--option2` and take the next argument that doesn't look like an option as its argument. And then `--option2` to look past the argument that's already been consumed by `--option1` and take the next one. And I'll be impressed if there's a `Getopt::Long` setting to do that.

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley, That would be silly :)   ...but possible by setting the `permute` option and making `--option1` and `---option2` flags. Then you do `my $option1 = $option1_flag ? shift(@ARGS) || die : undef;` and similarly for option2.

Comment: eh sorry that this is a bit unclear. In this case I don't actually want --option1 or --option2 to set anything, I just want to create a warning/check against something like this from happening.

So if somebody tried running my program the way I did it in my original post, they would get some type of error message

Comment: You don't want option2 set to anything when you provide `--option2 somethingElse`, but you do when it's `--option2 arg1` ...what?

Comment: As for option 1, yes, you want to make the value optional, and you want to warning if no value was provided (i.e. if the value is the empty string).  A rather silly thing to do as it makes things way more complicated than they have to be.

Comment: "You don't want option2 set to anything when you provide --option2 somethingElse, but you do when it's --option2 arg1 ...what? – ikegami 25 mins ago"

sorry again, let me clarify with this:
myprog.pl --option1 something --option2 somethingElse arg1 arg2 arg3

In other words, I don't want option1 or option2 to use any of the mandatory args (1,2,3).

Comment: It won't. You provided values for them.

Comment: I don't want something like this to happen though:

myprog.pl --option1 something --option2 arg1 arg2 arg3

where option2 would leech arg1

Comment: This gets more and more confusing. If you say `option2=s` then `option2` takes an argument. That's not "leeching", it's doing what you told it.

Comment: The I repeat my earlier question: You don't want option2 set to anything when you provide `--option2 somethingElse`, but you do when it's `--option2 arg1` ...what? What's the difference???